# CSS3 Vertically align centre after transform 90deg

Tags: css, rotation, vertical-alignment, text-align

I am looking for a way to centrally align the text of a tab after it has been rotated 90 deg. The tabs can have varying heights so it cannot simply be done by altering the absolute positioning with exacting coordinates.

Here is a FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/gPAhK/22/ Try and centre the text

```
.vtab .trigger li {
    display:block; width:40px; height:200px; border-radius:10px 0 0 10px; margin:0 0 -50px 2px; z-index:10; cursor:pointer; position:relative;
    background:url(http://www.divethegap.com/boris/tabs-large.png) no-repeat;
}
.vtab .trigger li b {
    display:block; line-height:46px; color:#222; -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg); text-align:center; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

​

Comment: You should rotate the `li`, not the `b`.

Comment: Not possible in this case for extra functionality. I have fixed it anyway quad erat demonstrandum will follow